# How can I recursively add dictionaries in Python from JSON?

Tags: python, json, recursion, dictionary

Dear Stackoverflow Members,

I have this JSON array, and it consists of the following items (basically):

```
{
    {
        'Name': 'x',
        'Id': 'y',
        'Unsusedstuff' : 'unused',
        'Unsusedstuff2' : 'unused2',
        'Children': []
    },
    {   'Name' : 'xx',
        'Id': 'yy',
        'Unsusedstuff' : 'unused',
        'Unsusedstuff2' : 'unused2',
        'Children': [{
            'Name': 'xyx',
            'Id' : 'yxy',
            'Unsusedstuff' : 'unused',
            'Unsusedstuff2' : 'unused2',
            'Children: []
        }
```

You get the basic idea. I want to emulate this (and just grab the id and the name and the structure) in a Python-list using the following code:

```
names = []
def parseNames(col):
    for x in col:
        if(len(x['Children'])> 0):
            names.append({'Name' : x['Name'], 'Id' : x['Id'], 'Children' : parseNames(x['Children'])})
        else:
            return {'Name' : x['Name'], 'Id' : x['Id']}
```

But, it only seems to return the first 'root' and the first nested folder, but doesn't loop through them all.

How would I be able to fix this?

Greetings,

Mats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read this, you're trying to convert this tree into a tree of nodes which only have Id, Name and Children. In that case, the way I'd think of it is as cleaning nodes.

To clean a node:

1. Create a node with the Name and Id of the original node.
2. Set the new node's Children to be the cleaned versions of the original node's children. (This is the recursive call.)

In code, that would be:

```
def clean_node(node):
    return {
        'Name': node['Name'],
        'Id': node['Id'],
        'Children': map(clean_node, node['Children']),
    }

>>> print map(clean_node, data)
[{'Name': 'x', 'Children': [], 'Id': 'y'}, {'Name': 'xx', 'Children': [{'Name': 'xyx', 'Children': [], 'Id': 'yxy'}], 'Id': 'yy'}]
```

I find it's easier to break recursive problems down like this - trying to use global variables turns simple things very confusing very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
def parseNames(col):
    for x in col:
        if(len(x['Children'])> 0):
            a = [{
                'Name' : x['Name'],
                'Id' : x['Id'],
                'Children' : x['Children'][0]['Children']
                }]
            parseNames(a)
        names.append({'Name' : x['Name'], 'Id' : x['Id']})
    return names
```

Output I get is

```
[{'Name': 'x', 'Id': 'y'}, {'Name': 'xx', 'Id': 'yy'}, {'Name': 'xx', 'Id': 'yy'}]
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. Same result, apparently.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That seems to get me a lot further. Yet the children get added as: <Recursion on list with id=4382318248> instead of their nodes. How does that work?

Comment: Sure thing! It now seems to give me some strange error like: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: Just did, seems to do a lot less than before. We must be missing something here. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a Json object with this:

```
import json
response = json.loads(my_string)
```

Now `response` is a dictionary with the keys of every Json object.

Comment: I figured out that much. This is is already the result of a json.loads() call (since I am able to do x['Name']). Edited the original post to clarify that

Comment: you should use a `while child in x['Children']` and not the `len` function.